# Read RDF/XML file in c#

Tags: c#, ontology, dotnetrdf

i'm struggling with reading OWL file in c# and i want to solve this problem, because i'm new to the semantic web world
I have read about the dotnetrdf library which is used for reading OWL file in c# and asp.net
through their documentation I found example about the Hello world
my question here
when i put the code

```
        IGraph g = new Graph();
        g.LoadFromFile("Helloworld.owl");
        IUriNode dotNetRDF = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.dotnetrdf.org"));
        IUriNode says = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://example.org/says"));
        ILiteralNode helloWorld = g.CreateLiteralNode("Hello World");
        ILiteralNode bonjourMonde = g.CreateLiteralNode("Bonjour tout le Monde", "fr");

        g.Assert(new Triple(dotNetRDF, says, helloWorld));
        g.Assert(new Triple(dotNetRDF, says, bonjourMonde));
        foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

it give me the output like this

```
http://www.dotnetrdf.org/ , http://example.org/says , Hello World
http://www.dotnetrdf.org/ , http://example.org/says , Bonjour tout le Monde@fr
```

so how can i display the result without the URI, please any idea about this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Console.WriteLine(t.ToString())` a string representation of the `Triple` objects is printed to the console. If you want to access a specific member (have a look at http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/dotNetRDF~VDS.RDF.Triple~Members.html) then you can access directly. e.g.

```
foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
{
     Console.WriteLine(t.Predicate);
     Console.WriteLine(t.Subject);
     Console.WriteLine(t.Object);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot to your answer, it was helpful for this code, but when i did the same thing for my code, it still give me the uri, my question regarding to my OWL file, which uei i need to use to put it in the code the object property or the data property ???? can you advise me ??

Comment: @brahamalboshi - Which property gives you still the uri ?

Comment: in my ontology i have class that devided into 5 subclass, but in this class it has object which called name, for example like ( Car) it has name (BMW) and it has subclass (type, year etc.) when i query for the name it gives me all the subclass uri

Comment: If u can help me with this, i will open new discussion and i will explain the issue

Comment: @brahamalboshi - I do not know if I can help you but someone in the community probably can. Please create a new question because this seems to be a new topic with some other code you should provide to clarify your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will open new question, i will try to mention you there

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the 'Object' property of the Triple:

```
        foreach (Triple t in g.Triples)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Object);
        }
```